# I can't set responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, responsive-design

I want to design a responsive menu. Actually everything is okay. İn fact I know what is the problem. But I can't fixed it. Also the codes are here: The Codes are here:  [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o53zoo8n/)

First condition like this:

[image]

And second condition like this:

[image]

When I click to menu no problem here, It's works. But if I use only one times and after İf I resize the screen, the menu is lost, doesn't come again. I think the problem is,  I open menu after that I close. Here, I doing display:none; But I can't fixed it.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<header>
        <section id="menuBar"><h1> MENU </h1> <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> </section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Hakkımda </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Portfolyo </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> İletişim </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
header{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px;
    z-index: 555555555555555;
    position: relative;
}

#menuBar{
    display: none;
}

header nav{
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
  list-style-type:none;
}

header nav ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

header nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-size: 17px;
}

@media (max-width:768px){

    section#menuBar{
        color: white;
        font-family: roboto;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    section#menuBar h1{
        line-height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    section#menuBar i{
        float: right;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

    header nav{

        height: 152px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    header nav ul{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: -45px;
        position: relative;

    }

    header nav ul li{
        float: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        border-bottom:1px solid whitesmoke;
        padding-bottom: 7px;
        background-color: #333;
        z-index: 444;
    }

    header nav ul li a{
        color: white;   

    }
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function(){

     var width = $(window).outerWidth();
    $('#menuBar').click(function(){
        $('header nav').slideToggle();

        $('header nav ul li').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('aktif1');
            $('a',this).addClass('aktif2');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('aktif1');
            $('a',this).removeClass('aktif2');

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Good example here - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be that you a bind resize event on your window, and check for the css break-point of `768px`

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).outerWidth() > 767)
        $('header nav').show();
    else
        $('header nav').hide();
});
```

Based on the width of window, reset the css properties `display`.

Comment: Thank you for helping but the problem is still have. I delete display:none and add your codes. But İt's not work. I can't understand how

Comment: Glad it helped. But to be honest, the approach given by Zazama is better than mine. Mine would close the menu when you've the menu opened and are trying to resize the window size to > 767px. It'd close. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if(!$('#menuBar').is(':visible') && !$('header nav').is(':visible')) {
    $('header nav').show();
  }
});
```

It checks if the menuBar is visible and if the menu itself is visible, if both is not the case, the window is bigger than the breakpoint in the css file and it will be shown.

Comment: Thumbs up. Just one pointer, we can replace slideToggle() with show(). slideToggle() makes it glittchy. :)